# What are the major reasons for run time differences between simple arithmetic operations - VBA vs. C++?

Tags: c++, performance, vba

This C++ program takes from 20 to 25 seconds to run on my relatively slow computer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int i;
double test = 456;

for (i = 0; i < 900000000; i++) {
    test = (test / 0.99999999);
}
    std::cout << "The value of test is " << test <<".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This excel vba macro takes from 37 to 40 seconds to run on my relatively slow computer:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Double
test = 456

For i = 0 To 900000000
    test = (test / 0.99999999)
Next i

Cells(1, 1).Value = test
End Sub
```

Is this difference typical(of C++ vs. non-compiled languages)? What are the major factors contributing to this difference in time? Is the fact that C++ is compiled the most important factor? Thanks.

Info:

For C++ I used Code::Blocks with GCC

For VBA I used Excel 2010.

For Code::Blocks it has a built in timer in it's console.

For excel I used a an iPhone stopwatch(didn't feeling like using CHighResTimer http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56900)

Comment: How are you timing the operations?  Are you timing the operations alone, or timing the process run overall?

Comment: Obviously it's because the vba for loop runs 900000001 iterations, whereas the C++ for loop only does 900000000.

Comment: @Void I am timing the entire program run time. Also see the information added under info:

Comment: The timer itself might be part of the problem. I'm suspicious that the Code::Blocks console timer is slowing down the run time.

Comment: "my relatively slow computer"..Time to get a new Computer!! ;) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmark is off, the margin should be way larger.

For instance, on my computer, the C++ code takes 7.46s (compiled without optimisations, timed with the Unix `time` tool); the VBA code by contrast took 46s. This is a much more realistic margin (but I wouldn’t have been surprised by an even larger one – conventional, non-optimising interpreters are usually at least a factor ten slower).

For one thing, VBA first has to read in the code and either interpret it line by line or transform it into an intermediate representation. Nevertheless, this intermediate code representation is still *interpreted*, not run directly by the CPU (or did you count the compilation time in C++?).<sup>1</sup>

In addition, VB(A) does a lot of redundant stuff in this code which is absent in C++: for instance, every single integer addition (which is implicit in your code in the incrementation of the `For` loop variable) is guarded against overflow. Essentially, this VB code

```
i = i + 1
```

is transformed to the following pseudo intermediate code:

```
if i + 1 overflows then
    raise an overflow error
end if
i = i + 1
```

… for *every* integer operation. That consumes quite a lot of runtime. The same goes for array (or here: cell) access operations.

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* VBA uses an intermediate representation called *P-code* rather than line by line code interpretation.

Comment: I also felt like the margin should be higher. I'm curious to know what kinds of margins other people come up with.

Comment: Compiling it with a "release" build target instead of "debug" brought it down to around 15 seconds for me.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is common and the biggest difference is that C++ is compiled. I'm surprised the difference isn't orders of magnitude larger. Most performance benchmarks show C/C++ to be 10+  times faster than scripting languages. How are you compiling the C++ code? I bet it runs in 5-10 seconds if compiled at the highest level of optimizations. If you're not already, you should compile with a `-O3` flag and time it.

I don't know much about VBA but if you're compiling the C++ with full optimizations I think it's more likely VBA is running through a just in time compiler and then executing the same as VB.NET would on the CLR. The performance you show there is more like VC++ vs. VB.NET than VC++ vs. any scripting language.

Comment: If he's using a modern compiler & turns on optimizations, I bet the loop drops to mere microseconds because the compiler will detect that it can precompute the final result & optimize the loop out entirely.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis in the last paragraph. The last time I was involved with VBA there was no port to the CLR but that was about 7 years ago, a lot could have happened since then.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah, I wish I could find more information on it... There must be something going on, I personally cannot believe a scripting language is running 1:2 with C++. Those numbers look much more like what you'd get out of Jython, IronPython, or JRuby.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal “I personally cannot believe a scripting language is running 1:2 with C++” – it isn’t, see my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah I saw that. I can't believe 1:6 either lol. It needs to be at least 1:20 to overcome my skepticism.

Comment: the -O3 flag didn't seem to change speed noticeably.(in this specific case)

Comment: @Stepan1010 The `std::out` could potentially be causing a bottle neck. Benchmarks show little variance in console IO between languages which have massive performance disparities elsewhere. For example a benchmark I was reading after you asked this showed Pythons double math to be about 80x slower than c++'s but it's stdIO was roughly the same, maybe 10 percent worse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the code lines in VBA are interpreted one-by-one over and over again, there must be some cache, otherwise the factor would be much larger than 1:2.

There can be many differences. Naturally the transition from a high-level language to CPU instuctions is different between different languages. C++ compilers are optimized for performance to meet a vast range of applications, which is probably not that important in Office products.

Answer (score 0):

I guess to put it into layman's terms imagine how VB was built, underneath it it is tapping something previously developed in C++. sO, NO MATTER HOW YOU SLICE IT there is a hidden C++ "middle man" beneath everything VB does in most cases, so certain things are being done twice in essence, such as those built in error safeguards, interps, etc.

I also found difference with VBA as a standard project or the same functionality built into a in process DLL with AutoCAD VBA but did not time the performance difference but I could see the in-process was running faster, as in VBA will also run faster than connecting into AutoCAD from external VB. It seems the allocate the available memory for you in VBA and VB is using its own process, I don't know but it is a place to look into for speed improvement.